# How can delay in program, until user response to run-time permission?

Tags: android

I have problem for run time permission.my code is:

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int i = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissions, 0x3);
    while (i == 0) {
        //
    }
    //
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 0x3:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
              Toast.makeText(G.context, "allowed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
               Toast.makeText(G.context, "deney", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break; } }}
```

I want whlie block run after user response permission. but while block dont wait for permission result. How can delay in program, until user response to run-time permission, and after run whlie and another line?

Comment: "How can delay in program, until user response to run-time permission, and after run whlie and another line?" -- you don't. You react in `onRequestPermissionResult()`. So, you isolate whatever code that you want to do once you have permission in some method. Call that from `onCreate()` if you already have permission, or call it from `onRequestPermissionResult()` once you get permission.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call the rest of your code if the "allowed" case of your onRequestPermissionResult method.

```
if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      Toast.makeText(G.context, "allowed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      //The rest of your code
} else {
      Toast.makeText(G.context, "deney", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      //Ask again
}
```